# google refine: use facet tools to infer map between two columns

Tags: google-refine

I've been searching but haven't found how to do this in refine.

I've got two columns of unique IDS. For each a in A, I want to find the top 10 closest matches in B.

My backup plan is to just use Levenshtein to iterate ... but Refine has such a nice iterface and many more algorithms implemented that I was hoping to be able to do some of the work using it.

Or is there another tool for doing this?

Comment: What is the definition of "closest match"?  Are the IDs numeric?  If there's a way to cluster the IDs, you could split the columns into two projects and use the cross() function to do the lookup on a cluster ID.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The IDs are text fields, with a lot of bad abbreviations on one side. After some investigation it looks like the matches just won't work very well without extra data for this particular set. I'll have a look at "cross()" ... I did not know about that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know you can use clustering algorithm like fingerprint or ngramFingerprint ([source](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions)) out of the clustering interface in Refine?

Using you IDS field, create a new column based on this column with the following expression: ngramFingerprint(value)

You can now cross with your other data set on this new column. This might help to get more matches.